# integrate silverlight in business application

Tags: silverlight

I am using business application template of silverlight(version 5).
I want to embed existing user controls & behaviours which i have downloaded from microsoft expression gallery.
Tell me the exact steps & expected changes to do so in my application
reply soon

Comment: You should paste what you've already tried. You can't expect people on SO to write your code for you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add the reference to your project or if you got access to the source code 'add existing items'
2. Add reference to in your .xaml e.g: `xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk`
3. Use it:  `<sdk:DataGrid/>`

alternatively

you could add vie the code behind: in xaml.cs create new instance of the object:

```
DownloadedUserControl control = new DownloadedUserControl;
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(control)
```